# ?? operator returns null when both values are not null

Tags: c#, linq

```
class ResultType 
{
    public string Value{ get; set; }
    public int Count{ get; set; }
}
var someList = new List<ResultType>(){new ResultType(){Value = "A"},new ResultType(){Value = "B"}};

ResultType z = someList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "A") ?? 
        someList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "B");
```

z should get the value of the item where Value is A (it has item with a value of A and with B, they are not null!) and yet I receive null, why does this happen?

```
 if(someList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "A")!=null) z= someList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "A");
```

this works.

Also when I do this

```
someList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "A")
```

and

```
someList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "B")
```

are saved into variables and then used as

```
z = a ?? b
```

this works as well

Please note that both of the values are not null!

screenshot
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ogq89shme1mhg44/Untitled.png

Comment: What is the type of someList? (i.e. can it be a value type)

Comment: May be small `a`? not caps ? or `Value` property is likely to be of `Object` type

Comment: try to create a for and print all the values to check what have inside.

Comment: the type is some custom structure that contains a string(Value) and and int

Comment: i debugged and it does contains the values, if i check if it's null first and then assign it does works

Comment: can it happen because the type i assign to is not nullable?

Comment: try someList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Equals("A")); just to make sure you aint comparing object references.

Comment: Show us a complete sample program which demonstrates the problem. without that we can't help

Comment: tried Equals, still null

Comment: Your code works fine for me. :)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ogq89shme1mhg44/Untitled.png

Comment: What happens if you put both results into separate variables, then null coalesce those?

Comment: @DaveShaw when in variables it actually works

Answer (score 2):

> why does this happens?

Answer is simple - there is neither exists item with Value equal to "A" nor exists item with Value equal to "B". Remember - values should be exactly "A" and "B" - uppercase strings without any white-spaces.

UPDATE: Your sample code works fine. As stated above - if you get null, then neither of values you search exist in collection.

[image]

Comment: this might happen even if it exist but `Value` is of type `Object`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel nope, if `Value` is `object` which is actually `string` then comparison will work without problems

Comment: exactly the same values, see code below, works without the ??

Comment: You're incorrect; You are forgetting the fact that if you compare `Object` with `string` using `==` operator then it will be compared as **reference** comparison rather than **value** comparison.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel my bad - forgot that only compile-time literal strings are interned by default

Comment: @atikot your real code differs from question. And answer is still same - there is no period equal to "FT" or your second value. Can you post screenshot of query `_allScores.Select(s => s.Period)` execution?

Comment: @atikot make sure you have used same language when typed "FT" literal

Comment: it is the same language

Comment: @atikot can you provide code which reproduces your problem? I.e. copy-paste period values from your application

Answer (score 0):

Because the result of both of your linq queries may be null. In other words

```
someList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "A")
```

returns null and

```
someList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "B")
```

returns null. Hence you get

```
z=null
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx.

> The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand.

What do you expect it to return if there is no other choise than null?

Comment: the values are not null, see the code i added, it does work without the ?? operator